# Distinct values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, distinct, sap-ase

I am trying to get distinct values for multiple columns in table.

for example if my table has COL1,COL2,COL3 as columns and I am running a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLEx
```

but what happens is depending on the data in one of the columns I am getting duplicate values in two other columns. If COL1 has 40 unique values and COL2 has only 10 unique values and COL3 has 5 unique values. I am getting 40 rows of data where COL1 is unique and COL2/COL3 has duplicate values. How do i get DISTINCT values for each column and replace the duplicate values by null values. I am doing this only to get distinct values for my drop down lists in a web page. I can always perform seperate query for each field but I think it is not very effective. Any help as I how I approach this?

Answer (score 4):

> I can always perform seperate query for each field

Yes! Do this!

> but i think it is not very effective.

It's probably fine. You can improve performance by adding a separate index to each column. If you are still worried that it will be slow, measure it to be sure. If it turns out that it really is a problem then you may want to consider using caching.

Comment: Especially as the question somewhat reads as the columns _may_ be 'unrelated'.  Either that, or perform the 'grouping' client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is what you're looking for, and it would only be ever-so-slightly more efficient than separate queries:

```
select distinct a, null, null
  from MyTable
 union
select distinct null, b, null
  from MyTable
 union 
select distinct null, null, c
  from MyTable
```

NOTE: This is certainly not the *correct* way to write sql queries, but does provide a possible solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Sybase happens to include row_nubmer(), you can do this with union all:

```
select seqnum, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3
from ((select row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
              col1, NULL as col2, NULL as col3
       from (select distinct col1
             from t
            ) t
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by col2) as seqnum
              NULL as col1, col2, NULL as col3
       from (select distinct col2
             from t
            ) t
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by col3) as seqnum
              NULL as col1, NULL as col2, col3
       from (select distinct col1
             from t
            ) t
      )
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum
```

This adds a sequence number to each value and then combines them using group by.

Comment: The OP is using Sybase ASE, which does not support the ROW_NUMBER() function to my knowledge...

Comment: I guess some databases based on Sybase do -- Sybase IQ and SQL Anywhere.  I could say it depends on the version being used.

Comment: I wouldn't say "depending on the version being used" -- Sybase ASE is a completely different product to Sybase IQ and SQLAnywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I used a single query but endedup using a Set to store unique values only once i get the resultSet. That way i am not loading the database with more than one query.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2 FROM t
```

can also use

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM t GROUP BY c1, c2
```

it worked for me.

Comment: This returns all combinations of col1/col2 values. This is not what the OP asked for.